# Spark json dataframe file not exist error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```python
df = spark.read.format("json").option("header", "true").load("test.json")
```

I have a scenario when the file is available in the path the code is running but need an idea if the json file is not available in the path how to handle the issue.

With AutoSys i can have a filewatcher job but need help if this can be handled with Spark.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the call to `load` in a try/except block:

```python
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
try:
    df = spark.read.format("json").option("header", "true").load("test.json")
except AnalysisException as e:
    print(e)
#u'Path does not exist: hdfs://path/to/file/test.json;'
```